# Angular 2 latest version (2.2.10) compatibility issues

Tags: angular

I am coding an example from a book. (If anyone is interested [the book is this one](https://www.manning.com/books/angular-2-development-with-typescript), the code can be downloaded by anyone and the sample in question is in the chapter3/auction folder).

If I run the same example from the downloaded code, it works perfectly. Mine is giving me the following error:

> Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <  SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>         at eval ()
>         at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:229:26)
>         at Zone.run (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43)
>         at http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:509:57
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:262:35)
>     Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles
>     Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/main.ts
>         at eval ()
>         at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:229:26)
>         at Zone.run (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43)
>         at http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:509:57
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:262:35)
>     Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles
>     Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/main.ts

After much grief and comparing both projects the only differences are the versions of the libraries being used so I believe the issue is some kind of incompatibility between the different dependencies.

This is the book's package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",

    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.37",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "^2.2.2"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

And this is mine:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.10",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
   "systemjs": "0.19.47",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

So far the only thing that I have been able to gather is that there is something not playing well between Angular and either Zone, SystemJS and/or rxjs. I have tried using older versions of Zone and rxjs but then I get warnings that Angular 2.4.10 require the versions that I am using.

Has anyone seen this same behaviour?
If so, is there anything that can be done to fix it?
If the only solution is to downgrade, to which versions?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear if ' book's package.json' worked for you or not. The problem can be in SystemJS configuration - which was not included. The question needs http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . A plunk/fiddle that can replicate the error would help.

Comment: @estus - You are right I did not mentioned that because I tried it after I created the post which did not work either but, your comment actually led me to the SystemJS configuration file and it turned out the author did not specify to update it by adding the "@angular/router" package in the packages property. Thank you.